# How to pass parameters to decoratorClass in MobileIconItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, air, blackberry-playbook

How to pass parameters to decoratorClass in MobileIconItemRenderer ? I have a custom control to display a metric (get from data collection), this control will be used as decoretorClass, my problem is that I couldn't set the metric parameter on my custom control, you can find below a sample code. How to do to pass values to a instance for my custom component ? Exist any way, or I have to re-make the MobileIconItemRenderer class ?

```
<s:List id="dealList" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" width="100%" height="100%"
                dataProvider="{dealService.lastResult.Response.Items.Item}" >
   <s:itemRenderer>
       <fx:Component>
           <s:MobileIconItemRenderer label="{data.Metric_Name}" messageField="Customer" decoratorClass="{MetricViewer}">
               <fx:Script>
                   <![CDATA[
                       import mobile.ui.component.mxml.MetricViewer;
                   ]]>
               </fx:Script>
           </s:MobileIconItemRenderer>
       </fx:Component>
   </s:itemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [one example](http://www.flex-blog.com/data-dependent-decoratorclass-in-mobileiconitemrenderer-example/).  However, it suggest to set a different decorator class based on the data.

Here is a [different example](http://www.flex-blog.com/checkbox-in-list-using-mobileiconitemrenderer-for-flex-mobile/), that seems to accomplish the same thing but does not use a decorator to do so.

There does not seem to be a documented API that you can use to access the instance of the decorator, but I bet if you drill into the code there is a way.